# AsyncTask and goBack

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

Can anyone tell me, why Back button returns a black page? I use parsing with Jsoup in AsyncTask. It looks like history does not exist. What should i change in my code to fix it?

```
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new ForumWebViewClient());
        String url = "https://forum.com";
        new ParseMyPageTask().execute(url);
    }
    private class ForumWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
            new ParseMyPageTask().execute(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    class ParseMyPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Elements body = doc.select("body");
                result = body.html();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webview.setInitialScale(0);
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://forum.com/",
                    "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=no\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/data/styles/black.css\"></head><body>" + result + "</body>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        }
    }   
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I really need your help!

Comment: Do you only intend to goBack on the WebView when the back button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the loadDataWithBaseURL and provide the same URL you are loading for the history!
Currently trying to figure our myself how to implemente the GOBACK so it get's parsed the same way!

[Visits are welcome](http://techboard.unden.at)